# Error when trying to bootstrap Angular component 'A platform with a different configuration has been created'

Tags: javascript, angular

I want to have a circular progress bar, so I have made a component:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-side-navbar-card',
      standalone: true,
      imports: [],
      templateUrl: './side-navbar-card.component.html',
      styleUrl: './side-navbar-card.component.css',
    })
    export class SideNavbarCardComponent {}
```

I found a working StackBlizt demo:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-h87v6z?file=src%2Fmain.ts

So I changed:

```
 selector: from `'my-app'` to `'app-side-navbar-card',`

`export class App` to `export class SideNavbarCardComponent` 

    bootstrapApplication(App, {
      providers: [..
```

to

```
    bootstrapApplication(SideNavbarCardComponent, {
      providers: [..
```

and got an error:

```
"A platform with a different configuration has been created. Please destroy it first."
```

What am I doing wrong, and how might I fix it?